# Is there some neat way to make Threads (in Java) wait for theoretical time units as opposed to using Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Currently working on a university assessment, so I won't share specifics and *I'm not asking for any explanation that will help me solve the main problem*. I've already solved the problem, but my solution might be considered a little messy.

Basically, we're working with concurrency and semaphores. There is some shared resource that up to `X (where X > 1)` number of threads can access at a time and an algorithm which makes it a little more complicated than just acquiring and releasing access. Threads come at a certain time, use the resource for a certain time and then leave. We are to assume that **no time is wasted when arriving, accessing, releasing and leaving the resource**. The goal is to demonstrate that the algorithm we have written works by outputting the times a thread arrives, accesses the resource and leaves for each thread.

I'm using a semaphore with `X` number of permits to govern access. And it's all working fine, but I think the way I arrive at the expected output might be a bit janky. Here's something like what I have currently:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    long alive = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try { Thread.sleep(arrivalTime * 1000); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {} // no interrupts implemented
    long actualArriveTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - alive;

    boolean accessed = false;
    while (!accessed) accessed = tryAcquire();
    long actualAccessTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - alive;

    try { Thread.sleep(useTime * 1000); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {} // no interrupts implemented
    release();
    long actualDepartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - alive;

    System.out.println(actualArriveTime);
    System.out.println(actualAccessTime);
    System.out.println(actualDepartTime);
}
```

I do it this way because where the expected output might be:

```
Thread  Arrival Access  Departure
A       0       0       3
B       0       0       5
C       2       2       6
...     ...     ...     ...
```

My output looks something like:

```
Thread  Arrival Access  Departure
A       0       0       3006
B       0       0       5008
C       2       2       6012
...     ...     ...     ...
```

I'm essentially making the time period much larger so that if the computer takes a fews milliseconds to `acquire()`, for example, it doesn't affect the number much. Then I can round to the nearest second to get the expected output. My algorithm works, but there are issues with this. **A:** It's slow; **B:** With enough threads, the milliseconds of delay may build so that I round to the wrong number.

**I need something more like this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int clock = 0;
    while (threadsWaiting) {
        clock++;
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Thread.waitUntil(clock == arrivalTime);

    boolean accessed = false;
    while (!accessed) accessed = tryAcquire();
    int accessTime = clock;

    int depatureTime = accessTime + useTime;
    Thread.waitUntil(clock == departureTime);
    release();

    System.out.println(arrivalTime);
    System.out.println(accessTime);
    System.out.println(departureTime);
}
```

Hopefully that's clear. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You are thinking about this the wrong way.  You don't want to wait "for" X time units.  You want to wait "until" a particular time OR "until" a particular event occurs.   It is not clear, but I think that the "theoretical time unit" you are talking about is actually *simulated* time ... in your simulation.  (Is that correct?)

Comment: @StephenC Thank you for your prompt response! And yes, that might be more what I'm looking for. I basically just need some way of ignoring the time it takes for the code I've written to do boiler plate stuff, and only care about the time it takes for a thread to access the resource.